# $this->con->prepare not working

Tags: php

i have config file for connection but when ever i use $this->con->prepare() or $this->con->query() are not working.
But when i make separate variable for connection its work fine below are example.

this code in not working

```
private function isEmailexist($email)
{
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM devices WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    echo "Rows : ".$rows;
}
```

---

This code work

---

```
private function isEmailexist($email)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "demo1");
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM devices WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    echo "Rows : ".$rows;
}
```

this is config file

```
class Config
{
    private $con;
    function __construct(){}
    function connect()
    {
        define('DB_USERNAME','root');
        define('DB_PASSWORD','');
        define('DB_NAME','demo1');
        define('DB_HOST','localhost');
        $con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        echo "Connection success...";
        return $this->con;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please extract a minimal example and add a precise error description. "doesn't work" is not a precise error description.

Comment: pass `$con` as a parameter in `isEmailexist` function and then use $con

Comment: what error is it throwing? how do you initialise $this->con

Comment: In your connect method, you define $con, but don't assign it to $this->con

Comment: You know, every time you call the connect method, you are recreating your constants...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with setting `$con` inside of `connect()`

You are using

```
// $con is only visible within the scope of the connect function
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
```

but it should be

```
// this will set the config class's $con property so that it is re-usable
$this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
```